# yarn is always stuck on sharp installation m1 mac os

Tags: node.js, nvm, sharp

I'm trying to install the packages of the project with `yarn` and it gets stuck on **sharp**.
I tried to install **libvips** with all dependencies via `brew install libvips` and still got the same error.

Dependencied list:

```
{
  "name": "@mike-north/typescript-fundamentals-v3",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Mike's TypeScript Fundamentals Course (v3)",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": "git@github.com:mike-north/ts-fundamentals-v3.git",
  "author": "Mike North <michael.l.north@gmail.com>",
  "license": "NOLICENSE",
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": [
    "packages/*"
  ],
  "volta": {
    "node": "14.7.0",
    "yarn": "1.22.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.0-0",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.16.7",
    "core-js": "^3.0.0",
    "lerna": "^4.0.0",
    "replace-in-file": "^6.2.0",
    "webpack": "^5.37.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "replace-in-file 'import chalk' 'import * as chalk' node_modules/gatsby-cli/lib/reporter/reporter.d.ts",
    "dev-website": "lerna run dev --scope website --stream",
    "dev-hello-ts": "lerna run dev --scope hello-ts --stream"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

The error:

```
error /Users/myname/Documents/Projects/ts-fundamentals-v3/node_modules/sharp: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node install/can-compile && node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)
Arguments: 
Directory: /Users/myname/Documents/Projects/ts-fundamentals-v3/node_modules/sharp
Output:
sharp: Using cached /Users/myname/.npm/_libvips/libvips-8.10.6-darwin-arm64v8.tar.br
prebuild-install WARN install No prebuilt binaries found (target=3 runtime=napi arch=arm64 libc= platform=darwin)
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
gyp info using node@18.7.0 | darwin | arm64
gyp info find Python using Python version 3.8.9 found at "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3"
(node:23828) [DEP0150] DeprecationWarning: Setting process.config is deprecated. In the future the property will be read-only.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
gyp info spawn /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/myname/Documents/Projects/ts-fundamentals-v3/node_modules/@npmcli/run-script/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/myname/Documents/Projects/ts-fundamentals-v3/node_modules/sharp/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/myname/Documents/Projects/ts-fundamentals-v3/node_modules/@npmcli/run-script/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/myname/Library/Caches/node-gyp/18.7.0/include/node/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/myname/Library/Caches/node-gyp/18.7.0',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/Users/myname/Documents/Projects/ts-fundamentals-v3/node_modules/@npmcli/run-script/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/myname/Library/Caches/node-gyp/18.7.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/myname/Documents/Projects/ts-fundamentals-v3/node_modules/sharp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
gyp info spawn args ]
gyp info spawn make
gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/nothing/../node-addon-api/nothing.o
  LIBTOOL-STATIC Release/nothing.a
env: python: No such file or directory
make: *** [Release/nothing.a] Error 127
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/myname/Documents/Projects/ts-fundamentals-v3/node_modules/@npmcli/run-script/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.6.0
gyp ERR! command "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/18.7.0/bin/node" "/Users/myname/Documents/Projects/ts-fundamentals-v3/node_modules/.bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/myname/Documents/Projects/ts-fundamentals-v3/node_modules/sharp
gyp ERR! node -v v18.7.0
```

Here is what I get from `npx envinfo --binaries --system`

```
System:
    OS: macOS 12.5
    CPU: (10) arm64 Apple M1 Max
    Memory: 108.36 MB / 32.00 GB
    Shell: 5.8.1 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 18.7.0 - /opt/homebrew/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.19 - /opt/homebrew/bin/yarn
    npm: 8.15.0 - /opt/homebrew/bin/npm
```

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it with installing **nvm** with the right *yarn* and **node** version, which was eventually 14.5.5 (not the one mentioned in the *package.json*).

Comment: OMg. after hours finally. switching from node16 to node14 make it throught. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, I was stuck all day on this! I was building an app inside a linux docker container (from my mac m1) and the npm install was hung up on the sharp install script (with no errors). Updating my docker image to node 14.5 & updating the sharp package version to 0.30.7 solved my issue.